# Can't apply texture to grid of vertices in Qt OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, textures, opengl-es-2.0

Right now I am working at creating a heightmap-based terrain grid, similar to the [Lighthouse 3D Terrain Tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/terrain/), except that I am using VBO's and EBO's. All has been going well until I have tried to texture my grid. Currently I am applying one texture that spans the entire grid. Using Window 7's sample Jellyfish picture, I end up with this:

[image: Terrain with distorted texture]

For those familiar with the picture, you can see that it is being repeated several times throughout the terrain grid. This led me to believe that my UV coordinates were being corrupted. However, if I use a function that always returns `0` to determine the height at each grid vertex, I end up with this:

[image: Solid blue grid]

Now I am thoroughly confused, and I can't seem to find any other resources to help me.

My code is as follows:

`generate_terrain()` function:

```
QImage terrainImage;
terrainImage.load(imagePath.data());
int width = terrainImage.width();
int height = terrainImage.height();

float uStep = 1.0f / width;
float vStep = 1.0f / height;

grid = new std::vector<float>;
indices = new std::vector<unsigned short>;

for (int i = 0; i <= height-1; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= width-1; ++j) {
        QVector3D vertex1{j, heightFunction(terrainImage.pixel(j, i)), i};
        QVector3D vertex2{j, heightFunction(terrainImage.pixel(j, i+1)), i+1};
        QVector3D vertex3{j+1, heightFunction(terrainImage.pixel(j+1, i+1)), i+1};

        QVector3D edge1 = vertex2 - vertex1;
        QVector3D edge2 = vertex3 - vertex1;
        QVector3D normal = QVector3D::crossProduct(edge1, edge2);
        normal.normalize();

        grid->push_back(vertex1.x());
        grid->push_back(vertex1.y());
        grid->push_back(vertex1.z());

        grid->push_back(normal.x());
        grid->push_back(normal.y());
        grid->push_back(normal.z());

        grid->push_back(j * uStep);
        grid->push_back(i * vStep);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < height-1; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width-1; ++j) {
        indices->push_back(i * width + j);
        indices->push_back((i+1) * width + j);
        indices->push_back((i+1) * width + (j+1));

        indices->push_back((i+1) * width + (j+1));
        indices->push_back(i * width + (j+1));
        indices->push_back(i * width + j);
    }
}

vertices = grid->size()/8;
indexCount = indices->size();
```

Texture Loading:

```
f->glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
f->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

QImage texture;
texture.load(texturePath.data());
QImage glTexture = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(texture);

f->glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, glTexture.width(), glTexture.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, glTexture.bits());
f->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
f->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Drawing:

```
f->glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
f->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
program->setUniformValue(textureUniform.data(), 0);

f->glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo.bufferId());
f->glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8*sizeof(float), 0);
f->glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8*sizeof(float), (void *) (sizeof(float) * 3));
f->glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8*sizeof(float), (void *) (sizeof(float) * 6));

f->glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo.bufferId());
f->glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
f->glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
f->glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
f->glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
f->glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
f->glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
f->glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Shaders:

Vertex:

```
attribute vec3 vertex_modelspace;
attribute vec3 normal_in;
attribute vec2 uv_in;

uniform mat4 mvp;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

varying vec2 uv;
varying vec3 normal;
varying vec3 fragPos;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vertex_modelspace, 1);
    uv = uv_in;
    normal = normal_in;

    fragPos = vec3(model * vec4(vertex_modelspace, 1));
}
```

Fragment:

```
varying vec2 uv;
varying vec3 normal;
varying vec3 fragPos;

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

void main(void)
{
    vec3 lightColor = vec3(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);

    float ambientStrength = 0.2;
    vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lightColor;

    vec3 norm = normalize(normal);
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(lightPosition - fragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDirection), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;

    vec3 color = texture2D(texture, uv).rgb;

    vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse) * color;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```

I am completely stuck, so any suggestions are welcome :)

P.S. I am also working at trying to get my lighting to look better, so any tips on that would be welcome as well.

Comment: How do you know that the texture coordinates are at attribute location 2? I don't see you defining (or querying) that anywhere in your code.

Comment: I don't, but I guess I will try that. I was under the impression that layout locations were assigned by the declaration order in the shader, so uv_in would have location 2 since it is the third attribute declared.

Comment: No, the declaration order is irrelevant. You have to either set the location with `glBindAttribLocation()` *before* linking the program, or get the automatically assigned locations with `glGetAttribLocation()` *after* linking the program.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll try that right now. And just to clarify, the result of `glGetAttribLocation()` is used in the `glAttribPointer()` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` calls?

Comment: Wow, none of the tutorials I looked at had ever mentioned this. But it works, thank you so much :) If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Cool. I'll either write an answer or find a duplicate later today.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is assuming values for the attribute locations, which are the values used as the first argument to `glVertexAttribPointer()` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray()`. For example here:

```
f->glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8*sizeof(float), 0);
f->glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8*sizeof(float), (void *) (sizeof(float) * 3));
f->glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8*sizeof(float), (void *) (sizeof(float) * 6));
```

you're assuming that the positions have location 0, the normals location 1, and the texture coordinates location 2.

This is not guaranteed by anything you have currently in your code. The order of the `attribute` declarations in the GLSL code does **not** define the location assignment. For example from the OpenGL 3.2 spec:

> When a program is linked, any active attributes without a binding speciﬁed through BindAttribLocation will be automatically be bound to vertex attributes by the GL.

Note that this does not specify **how** the automatic assignment of the locations is done. This means that it's implementation dependent.

To fix this, there are two approaches:

1. You can call `glBindAttribLocation()` for all your attributes **before** the shader program is linked.
2. You can query the automatically assigned locations by calling `glGetAttribLocation()` **after** the program is linked.
3. In newer OpenGL versions (GLSL 3.30 and later, which is the version matching OpenGL 3.3), you also have the option to specify the location directly in the GLSL code, using qualifiers of the form `layout(location=...)`.

None of these options has any major advantages over the others. Just use the one that works best based on your preferences and software architecture.